# How to check if a FileInputStream is "full"

Tags: android

I'm trying to write a file on users mobile following this example

[Storage Options [data-storage]](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

I want to create that file the first time users run my app.

After the first time users run my app, I want FIRST read the file, and THEN write something in it (if i need).

Following the example above i'm using `FileInputStream stream= openFileInput(FILENAME)`,

Is there a way to know if the file i put in FileInputStream exists by checking the fIleInpuStream itself?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867334/check-if-a-file-exists-before-calling-openfileinput

Comment: i would say that if you can read from it, you can safely assume it exists, but you couldn't open it if it didn't exist, meaning you'd have to catch a FileNotFoundException

Comment: on the side note, why don't you use preferences to store your application specific data? It is a standard way of "remembering" application information rather than using a file in SD card. Also what happens, when the user changes/removes his sd card? Your application will think that it is getting launched for the first time. Is it what you are expecting?

Comment: @DurairajP : openFileInput open a private file for this context. It is not on the SDCard (as it is private). It uses the internal storage, as the Storage Options article states.

Answer (score 1):

Thank everybody for your help.
Maybe the best way to do what i want to do was suggested by @Durairaj P.

I used Preferences.

But i'm still wondering if it's suitable and appropriate for what i want to do. I want to keep track of the points that users earn while playing my game; when users re-open my app, i have to show all the points they earned since they installed my app. I'm just wondering if Preferences are suitable and appropriatefor this, or if i should use something else.

Anyway i post my code, it might help someone

```
public class managePreferences{
Context context;    

    managePreferences(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }


    public String readPreference(String fieldName, String defaultValue){    
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFERENCES", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String value = prefs.getString(fieldName, defaultValue);
        return value ;
    }


    public void writePreference(String fieldName, String value){
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFERENCES", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(fieldName, value);
        editor.commit();

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use

```
context.fileList();
```

and test if my file is somewhere. (quickest way is to make a List of it and use `contains()`) :

```
Arrays.asList(context.fileList()).contains(FILENAME);
```

Comment: thanks for the downvote, someone. care to elaborate as to why the error is wrong?